# convert duration string greater than 24 hours to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas

I have some duration strings, some sample greater than 24 hours. how can I convert such strings to datetime?

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['A','01:00:00'],
    ['B','23:10:00'],
    ['C','13:20:05'],
    ['D','27:30:25']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','duration'])
df['duration'] = pd.to_datetime(df['duration'],format='%H:%M:%S')
print(df)
```

Comment: What is your expectation for row `D`? would it be `pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']) + pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) that handles very well hours above 24:

```
ref_date = 0 # epoch, you can also use a given date
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']).add(pd.Timestamp(ref_date))
```

Output:

```
  ID            duration
0  A 1970-01-01 01:00:00
1  B 1970-01-01 23:10:00
2  C 1970-01-01 13:20:05
3  D 1970-01-02 03:30:25
```